# How to put datas of a plist includes rows of dictionaries to an array of dictionaries to use it on codes

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I am working on a swift project and I need to read a long plist includes string data and then put it on an array of strings to use it on codes. and I did it and it works fine. I used these codes to reach it

```
if let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Abbrivation", withExtension: "plist") {
    if let englishFromPlist = NSArray(contentsOf: URL) as? [String] {
        myPlistArray = englishFromPlist
    }
}

print("count of plist is:",myPlistArray.count)
```

now my project has changed a little and I have to work with a plist includes rows of dictionaries like the image below

[image]

now I have to change all the strings definition for array to dictionary but my problem is that all changes confronts an error. and I searched a lot how to do it but it failed.

now my question is that how to put data of a plist includes some rows of dictionaries to an array of dictionaries. I will appreciate any kinds of help. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are highly encouraged to decode the property list into a struct with the `Codable` protocol

```
struct Country : Decodable {
    let flagEmoji, abb, countryName, pName : String

    private enum CointryKeys : String, CodingKey { case flagEmoji, abb = "Abb", countryName, pName }
}

var countries = [Country]()

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Abbrivation", withExtension: "plist")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
do {
    countries = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Country].self, from data}
} catch { print(error) }

print("count of plist is:", countries.count)
```

The code must not crash. If it does you made a design mistake

Note:

**Never** use the API `NSArray(contentsOf` in Swift to read a property list file from disk. Use always `PropertyListSerialization` or `PropertyListDecoder`

Comment: It has errors on this line `countries = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Country].self, from data}
`

Comment: thank you for the information about NSArray . I will keep my eyes on it to never repeat . but can you explain more why? or suggest me something to read about it ?! thank you

Comment: another question, do you think its better I work with three separate Plist of strings instead of one plist includes dictionries? Thank you very much for your time

Comment: I updated the answer to catch a Decoding Error (however the given plist is supposed to be decoded without errors). `NSArray/ NSDictionary` are types which belong to Objective-C. In Swift use the native strong-typed arrays and dictionaries. One plist including all data is recommended.

Comment: Thank you for all the information. now there is no error and the code runs. but do you know why the countries.count is zero? I changed the print code to this `print("countries.count:", countries.count)` and the result is `countries.count: 0`

Comment: My code matches the property list in the question. If you get zero this is not the real plist.

Comment: I found the problem. it seems it could not understand abb and I change it to Abb and it works fine. seems perfect. thank you very very much.